# Haskell Error: Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> a -> a -> a)

Tags: debugging, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and am trying to run the following example code from my book:

entire file:

```
-- my name

splitAt1   ::  [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAt1 xs = (take 2 xs, drop 2 xs)
```

I'm testing by running the line:

```
splitAt1 [1 2 3 4]
```

The idea is that the input array is split into two arrays at the index 2. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Non type-variable argument
  in the constraint: Num (a -> a -> a -> a)
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
When checking that ‘it’ has the inferred type
  it :: forall a a1 a2 a3.
        (Num a1, Num a2, Num a3, Num (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> a)) =>
        ([a], [a])
```

Could anyone help me decode the error message and perhaps what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Is that all the code? What version of GHC? Can't seem to be able to reproduce it here: http://rextester.com/YLAV57098

Comment: Yes, that is all the code. It is version 7.10.2.

Comment: The code works fine for me with 7.10.2. Can you probably paste your entire file ?

Comment: @Sibi my entire file is pasted above. It's... not much.

Comment: The list in your test line should be written as `[1, 2, 3, 4]` (note the commas).

Comment: Just saw the edit. Deleting my answer since it's not relevant, but leaving a comment to point to the release notes just in case: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/release-7-10-1.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function is fine, it's your argument that's off.

Try `splitAt1 [1,2,3,4]` instead of `splitAt1 [1 2 3 4]` and it should work.